# Do we have an API for sitecore 6.6

Tags: webapi

I want to acess the sitecore items from outside context . Do we have an API to acess Sitecore Items in Sitecore 6.6?

Answer (score 5):

https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Item%20Web%20API/SitecoreItemWebApi12.aspx

**Sitecore Item Web API 1.2.**

This version of the module only runs on Sitecore CMS 6.6.0 rev. 131211 (6.6.0 Update-7) and later. It seems you will need to install it as a module (it was not included in the product - that happened in 7.1).